# Wordpress plugin: Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent

Tags: php, wordpress

I create a wordpress plugin, and I want to export some data to pdf, to do this I use **dompdf**, but unfornatly, I get this error:
**Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent**

I make a research in the net, but I don't found a solution.
This is my code, and please tell me what is wrong.

```
    <?php
ob_start();
$html=content();

if($html){
  require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html($html);
  $dompdf->render();
  $dompdf->stream("order.pdf");
}else{

  echo "Look like something is wrong here .";
}
function content(){
    $content = null;
    $content .= "<table class='mytable' width='100%' height='10%' border='1' cellspacing='0'>
                     <tr>
                      <th>DATE</th>
                      <th>ORDER</th>
                      <th>SUTNAME</th>
                      <th> COMMENTS</th>
                     </tr>";

  $content .= "</table>";

  return $content;
}
?>
```

Comment: Make sure that no content is sent before you try to output the PDF. In your code, those blank spaces before <?php will actually send content and break DOMPDF.  Warnings and notices will break DOMPDF as well if you have display errors set to On.

Comment: @aminoo Did you manage to fix this??? I am getting the same issue. Please let me know if you have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable all messages , execute the instructions prone to failure and reactivate the messages to restore stability to the system.

```
    // Desactivamos los posibles warning para que no se envien los headers
    error_reporting(0);

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);  
$dompdf->render();

    // Save file    
    $output = $dompdf->output();
    $dest = "/your-directory/final_file.pdf";        
    $result = file_put_contents($dest, $output);        

    // Reactivamos los warning            
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);                        

    if( $result ) {
        // Send file       
        $dompdf->stream($dest);            
    }
    else{            
         echo "<p> An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later or contact support. </p>";          
    }
```

Comment: The comments you added to the code would be more helpful if they were all in English. :/